# passing value from class to show on different form & click event handling programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, class, inheritance

ive currently created a chess board populated with images of the pieces in place and have coloured the board etc, i have 2 issues with the click event method of which im hoping you could help me on? when a square is clicked my current method changes the sqaure colour and displays a messagebox showing the xy co-ordinates and type of piece or just co-ordinates if its not occupied by a piece :

Issue 1 : How can i get the colour to change back to its original if i click the same sqaure again or a different sqaure?

Issue 2 : How would i instead of showing a meesagebox, display the information on Form1.cs in a textbox or label?

The following is my code from my GridSqaure.cs class:

```
namespace Chess
{
    public class GridSquare : PictureBox
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        private ChessPiece piece;

        public int X { get { return x; } }
        public int Y { get { return y; } }

        public ChessPiece Piece 
        {
            get { return piece; }
            set 
            {
                piece = value;
                if (value == null)
                    this.BackgroundImage = null;
                else
                    this.BackgroundImage = piece.GetImage();
            }
        }

        public GridSquare(int x, int y)
        {
            int ButtonWidth = 64;
            int ButtonHeight = 64;
            int Distance = 20;
            int start_x = 10;
            int start_y = 10;

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            this.Top = start_x + (x * ButtonHeight + Distance + x);
            this.Left = start_y + (y * ButtonWidth + Distance + y);
            this.Width = ButtonWidth;
            this.Height = ButtonHeight;
            this.Text = "X: " + x.ToString() + " Y: " + y.ToString();

            this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            this.Click += new System.EventHandler(gridSquare_Click);
        }

        private void gridSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridSquare gs = (GridSquare)sender;
            if (gs.Piece != null)
                {
                    //Change: need to show xy of sqaure clicked on a label or textbox on the main window.
                MessageBox.Show("You clicked a " + gs.Piece.GetName() + " at (" + gs.X + ", " + gs.Y + ")");

                //Change: need to click for change in colour, then second click to revert back
                this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                } 
            else
                {
                    //Change: need to show xy of clicked square but including meesage stating the sqaure needs to be occupied by a piece.
                    MessageBox.Show("You clicked (" + gs.X + ", " + gs.Y + ")");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid having a class handle one of its own events. It isn't a good practice.

Instead, I would use a callback strategy.

First, recode `GridSquare` like this:

```
public class GridSquare : PictureBox
{
    /* As before */

    public GridSquare(int x, int y, Action<GridSquare> clicked)
    {
        /* As before */
        this.Click += (s, e) => clicked(this);
    }

    /* NO private void gridSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) */
}
```

Now it is up to the calling code to do the hard work.

I assume that you're creating the board using something like nested for loops that add each created `GridSquare` to the form's `Controls` collection. If that's the case you would need to write your code like this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(new GridSquare(x, y, clicked));
    }
}
```

Now you just need to define `clicked` - the callback when each `GridSquare` is clicked - and that code looks like this:

```
GridSquare lastClicked = null;
Color lastBackColor = Color.Transparent;

Action<GridSquare> clicked = gs =>
{
    lastClicked.BackColor = lastBackColor;
    if (!lastClicked.Equals(gs))
    {
        lastClicked = gs;
        lastBackColor = gs.BackColor;
        gs.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        var inner = gs.Piece != null
            ? String.Format("a {0} at ", gs.Piece.GetName())
            : "";
        var msg = String.Format("You clicked {0}({1}, {2})", inner, gs.X, gs.Y);
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
};
```

Obviously this code goes before the creation of the grid squares.

This should be relatively easy to follow, but if not, just ask and I'll elaborate.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: just trying to get my head round this, ive followed your logic, however i get 2 errors, (First) from your initial set of code the last line shows an error "the name 'clicked' does not exist in the current context. (Secondly) from your second set of code, it gives an error "chess.gridSqaure does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments.

Comment: @Rg786 - It sounds like you didn't get the 'GridSquare' constructor signature copied correctly from my code. It should be 'public GridSquare(int x, int y, Action<GridSquare> clicked)'.

Comment: I think i may have grossly confused myself, ive had a re-think and have gone the route of adding a method to 'GridSqaure' called ResetColour(). then added an If statement envoking the resetcolour in the click method. seems to be working fine. as for the label, i also had a re-think and opted to go for the ToolStripStatusLabel which also worked fine... so far....

Answer (score 1):

First store the actual color of the box in an object of Color class, lets assume the object name is "BoxColor" and now see the following code.

```
if (gs.Piece != null) 
{      
    //Change: need to show xy of sqaure clicked on a label or textbox on the main window.       
    label1.Text = "You clicked a " + gs.Piece.GetName() + " at (" + gs.X + ", " + gs.Y + ")";       
   //Change: need to click for change in colour, then second click to revert back           
  this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;  
}        
else         
{             
    //Change: need to show xy of clicked square but including meesage stating the sqaure needs to be occupied by a piece.   
     this.BackColor = BoxColor //setting back the original color if the box is clicked again.
     label1.Text = "You clicked (" + gs.X + ", " + gs.Y + ")";     
}
```

And also put one boolean variable enable it only when the color of the box is changed from its actual color and now if the user clicks on any other boxes check for these flag and if its true reset the color.

Comment: Thank you, your response gave me an idea for setting the colour in my code. see the first response code

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a `boolean` variable on the scope of your class `GridSquare`. Then use this variable on `gridSquare_Click` event handler like this:

   ```
   public class GridSquare : PictureBox
   {
      bool isFirstClick = true;
      .....
      .....
      .....
      private void gridSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
              if(isFirstClick)
              {
                  isFirstClick = false; 
                  //Set one color
               }
              else
              {
                  isFirstClick = true;
                  //Set other color
              } 
        } 
   }
   ```
2. Simply use `Text` property of `Label` or `TextBox`.

Comment: @Kvn - Thank you for your input, your way did get me thinking of alternative ways to get what i did. see first response.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ammended my original code to:

```
namespace Chess
{
public class GridSquare : PictureBox
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    private static GridSquare lastClicked;
    private static ChessBoard board;

    private ChessPiece piece;

    public int X { get { return x; } }
    public int Y { get { return y; } }
    public static ChessBoard Board { set { board = value; } }

    Color LightTile = Color.Beige;
    Color DarkTile = Color.SandyBrown;

    public ChessPiece Piece 
    {
        get { return piece; }
        set 
        {
            piece = value;
            if (value == null)
                this.BackgroundImage = null;
            else
                this.BackgroundImage = piece.GetImage();
        }
    }

    public GridSquare(int x, int y)
    {
        int ButtonWidth = 64;
        int ButtonHeight = 64;
        int Distance = 20;
        int start_x = 10;
        int start_y = 10;

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.Top = start_x + (x * ButtonHeight + Distance + x);
        this.Left = start_y + (y * ButtonWidth + Distance + y);
        this.Width = ButtonWidth;
        this.Height = ButtonHeight;
        this.Text = "X: " + x.ToString() + " Y: " + y.ToString();

        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        this.Click += new System.EventHandler(gridSquare_Click);
    }

    private void gridSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridSquare gs = (GridSquare)sender;

        if (lastClicked != null)
            lastClicked.ResetColour();

        //Change: need to click for change in colour, then second click to revert back
        this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        lastClicked = this;

        if (gs.Piece != null)
        {
            board.StatusLabel.Text = "You clicked a " + gs.Piece.GetName() + " at (" + gs.X + ", " + gs.Y + ")";
        }
        else
        {
            board.StatusLabel.Text = "You clicked (" + gs.X + ", " + gs.Y + ")";
        }
    }

    public void ResetColour()
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
            if (y % 2 == 0)
                // If x=Even y=Even
                this.BackColor = LightTile;
            else
                // If x=Even y=Odd
                this.BackColor = DarkTile;
        else
            if (y % 2 == 0)
                // If x=Odd y=Even
                this.BackColor = DarkTile;
            else
                // If x=Odd y=Odd
                this.BackColor = LightTile;
    }
}
```

}